# Use jest.run() or jest.runCLI() to run all tests or ways to run jest programmatically

Tags: jestjs

How do I use `jest.run()` or `jest.runCLI()` to run all tests programmatically? What am I suppose to feed as an argument?

I tried to find documentation regarding them but fail.

And if the above functions don't work, what am I supposed to call if I want to run jest programmatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jest is not supposed to be run programmatically. Maybe it will in the future.

Try to run following:

```
const jest = require("jest");

const options = {
  projects: [__dirname],
  silent: true,
};

jest
  .runCLI(options, options.projects)
  .then((success) => {
    console.log(success);
  })
  .catch((failure) => {
    console.error(failure);
  });
```

As `success` in `then` callback an object will be passed, containing `globalConfig` and `results` keys. Have a look on them, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Note that the `runCLI` promise will also resolve (call `.then`) in case tests _fail_. It will only reject (`.catch`) if jest itself cannot start, e.g. due to problems in jest global setup.

Comment: do you know if there is any way to programmatically mock a component in that same file? or programmatically pass the content of setupTests?

Answer (score 6):

From what I have experienced so far, utilizing `run()` requires to you define a static config and then pass arguments to Jest much like you would normally using the [Jest CLI](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#onlychanged).

Utilizing `runCLI()` allows you to dynamically create a config and provide it to Jest.

I opted for the former just because I wanted to only expose a few of the Jest CLI options for a global configuration:

```js
import jest from "jest";
import { configPaths } from "../_paths";
import { Logger } from "../_utils";

process.env.BABEL_ENV = "test";
process.env.NODE_ENV = "test";

const defaultArgs = ["--config", configPaths.jestConfig];

const log = new Logger();

const resolveTestArgs = async args => {
  let resolvedArgs = [];

  if (args.file || args.f) {
    return [args.file || args.f, ...defaultArgs];
  }

  // updates the snapshots
  if (args.update || args.u) {
    resolvedArgs = [...resolvedArgs, "--updateSnapshot"];
  }

  // tests the coverage
  if (args.coverage || args.cov) {
    resolvedArgs = [...resolvedArgs, "--coverage"];
  }

  // runs the watcher
  if (args.watch || args.w) {
    resolvedArgs = [...resolvedArgs, "--watch"];
  }

  // ci arg to update default snapshot feature
  if (args.ci) {
    resolvedArgs = [...resolvedArgs, "--ci"];
  }

  // tests only tests that have changed
  if (args.changed || args.ch) {
    resolvedArgs = [...resolvedArgs, "--onlyChanged"];
  }

  return [...defaultArgs, ...resolvedArgs];
};

export const test = async cliArgs => {
  try {
    const jestArgs = await resolveTestArgs(cliArgs);
    jest.run(jestArgs);
  } catch (error) {
    log.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

Comment: Useful! Do you know if there's a way to add  args to runCLI? theoretically they would just persist, but the don't seem to be for me. I guess I will switch to run and pass the config via `--config`

Answer (score 2):

Here's example from my post on [How to run Jest programmatically in node.js (Jest JavaScript API)](https://medium.com/@slavafomin/how-to-run-jest-programmatically-in-node-js-jest-javascript-api-492a8bc250de).

This time using TypeScript.

## Install the dependencies

```
npm i -S jest-cli
npm i -D @types/jest-cli @types/jest
```

## Make a call

```typescript
import {runCLI} from 'jest-cli';
import ProjectConfig = jest.ProjectConfig;


const projectRootPath = '/path/to/project/root';

// Add any Jest configuration options here
const jestConfig: ProjectConfig = {
 roots: ['./dist/tests'],
 testRegex: '\\.spec\\.js$'
};

// Run the Jest asynchronously
const result = await runCLI(jestConfig as any, [projectRootPath]);

// Analyze the results
// (see typings for result format)
if (result.results.success) {
  console.log(`Tests completed`);
} else {
  console.error(`Tests failed`);
}
```

Also, regarding @PeterDanis answer, I'm not sure Jest will reject the promise in case of a failed tests. In my experience it will resovle with `result.results.success === false`.

Comment: it seems like runCLI is no longer an export?

Comment: you should use `import { run } from 'jest-cli';` instead

Comment: The API has recently been reorganized.  Use `import { runCLI } from "jest";`

Answer (score 1):

If all your configs are in the jest.config.js, you can just code like this:

```js
const jest = require('jest')

jest.run([])
```