# Can I run jest tests as regular js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jestjs

Jest uses `describe` and `it` and `expect` without you having to `require` them. This is okay because if you have a test file called `test.spec.js`, you'll never execute it directly by issuing the command `node test.spec.js`.

I want to execute it using node as a standard js file, without having to use jest's cli or `npm test`. Is it possible to do that?

For instance, I'd convert the following file:

```
// taken from documentation
const user = require('./users.js')
it('works with promises', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  return user.getUserName(4).then(data => expect(data).toEqual('Mark'));
});
```

To something like

```
var {describe, it, expect} = require('jest-primitives') 
const user = require('./users.js')
it('works with promises', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  return user.getUserName(4).then(data => expect(data).toEqual('Mark'));
});
```

So that it's a self-contained js file, which can be run using just node.

A complete list of globals that jest provides is given [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html).

Comment: Jest did few magics to make tests easy. It replaces standard nodejs module resolution, so that it can support projects with complex webpack setup, plus supporting transpiling. It also monkey patch few global objects' prototypes, which is controversial. Even if you managed what you want, it's very likely you at least bypassed jest's replacement of nodejs module solution. That will cause different behavior than standard jest tests.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between your first and second example aside from that you're not using the `jest cli` to run your tests? Either way, you have to install `jest`, so it's not like you're not installing extra dependencies if you take the `jest cli` out of the picture.

Comment: I want to understand "the magic" that jest is doing with its primitive global functions. One way to do that is to see how easy it would be to replicate without using `jest cli`, which is this question.

Comment: A practical use might be that you can't "hack on" jest js files (say, to improve or customize some functionality with test framework itself) the same way you can "hack on" regular js files (e.g. I can wrap around jest's `it` function in my own `it` function which runs some custom code (e.g. logging test name to a file, wrapping test function in another function) and then calls jest's `it` function)

Comment: It sounds like you are asking this same question. Have you looked into `jest.runCLI`?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827216/use-jest-run-or-jest-runcli-to-run-all-tests-or-ways-to-run-jest-programmati

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it technically possible? Yes.

Should you? Probably not. (But there are better ways - tl;dr use `tape`)

#### Background

Jest is a [*test harness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness).

Jest is not the only test harness to use `describe()` and `it()`. These are typical test keywords for [behavior-driven development (BDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development). You'll also find them used with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and others.

`describe()` and `it()` are functions that interface with the test harness, telling it to add a test suite and a test case, respectively. The test harness then runs the test cases, collects the results, formats the results and outputs them.

#### Why you shouldn't do this with Jest

Generally, you should use technology as idiomatically as possible. This makes it easier for others to read, understand, and work with your technology.

In particular, using Jest in this way will be self-implemented, hacky, buggy and generally incomprehensible to anyone not familiar with your code. That being said, it should be possible.

#### How you might attempt that with Jest

Jest defines *runner* packages in their Jest monorepo. One is [Circus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-circus), the other is [Jasmine2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-jasmine2).

Circus [exports `describe()`, `it()` and some other keywords](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/d7a7b4294a4507030f86fe4f78e1790f53d0bda9/packages/jest-circus/src/index.ts#L207), though these are not really useful to us, as these functions only internally create the test suites and test cases but do not expose them to us or give us a way to run them.

Jasmine2 [exports](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/index.ts#L217) [an executable function](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/index.ts#L217) which [returns a Promise of a test result](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/index.ts#L31). The [code for jasmineAsyncInstall](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmineAsyncInstall.ts#L179) creates most of the keywords in the env or globally, and you might be able to use these.

What you'd want to do here is define `it()` and `describe()` functiions, either globally, as exports (if you'd like to use them as in the code sample in the question), or hackily by defining them inside the scope of the main module. These functions should register test cases and test suites. You'll want to either keep track of the test cases and run them later, or run them right away and keep track of the test results.

The problem now lies in determining when the test module has finished running. That is, when all of the `describe()` and `it()` have executed (whether or not the test cases themselves have executed), as well as any other incident code (code that isn't in any block). There is no good way to handle this, and here's where it may get hacky again. The easiest way is probably to add a listener to `process.on('exit'`.

#### Why that doesn't matter

A test harness is generally just a test runner and a reporter. Jest, in particular, is just a collection of components, all of which are configurable.

If we're just pulling a function here and a variable there from Jest, can we really say that we're still using it? Why do we even want to? There's really no reason to use Jest here. If you don't like the way it runs tests, you should use a different test harness instead of trying to modify it. If you like the reporter, Jest [exports a package containing only the reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jest/reporters).

#### A better way to make test files runnable

Use [tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tap) or [tape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape). These are designed to be run the way you want, and are configurable.

Example:

```
const test = require('tape');
const MyClass = require('../src/my-class');

test('MyClass.doSometing should be true', (t) => {
    const result = MyClass.doSomething();

    if (result === true) {
      t.pass('The test passed! Hooray! Our class MyClass is seemingly error-free!');
    } else {
      t.fail('Oh noes. Our test has failed. Why am I such a bad programmer....?');
    }

    t.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a lot of research to get to the right library.

The most suitable one that I found so far is [Jest Lite](https://www.chaijs.com/). This guy has done a great job.

Another solution I found is a workaround with [Chai.js](https://www.chaijs.com/). Install chai and import the expect from the library. Run expect statement. Unfortunately, it does not return a promise or result. You can just get the job done with a try-catch.